# Tethering Pi to Computer for Internet

Tags: networking, wifi, ethernet, headless

Good Evening, 
Ideas- I'm operating at work so I'm very limited to my "lab" to play around with stuff. Anyway- here's what I've got-
Ubiquiti EdgeRouter 8
Raspberry Pi 4
Windows 10 Machine (with VNC, Teamviewer, Oracle, and putty/winscp)
iPhone providing internet to laptop via wifi or usb tether
Ubiquiti Nanostation M5 providing wifi hotspot

I'm playing with the EdgeRouter and optimizing/configuring it to take home later for my home network. However, I've been effectively using it as a switch basically trying to use the Pi. I've started a headless pi and can ssh into it but I need internet to get teamviewer installed on it and get a GUI.

Currently loaded Ubuntu on it.

Anyone have ideas on how to do this? I also have a crossover cable if that was helpful....

Open ears.

Thanks

Comment: Is the pi currently connected to the internet? Or is that what you are trying to achieve so that you can view the pi's screen using TeamVeiwer.

Comment: unfortunately my source of internet at the moment is the iphone...so no, consider it a brand new, effectively untouched pi that's headless......and I've just been using the EdgeRouter to access it (as a switch) because that's what I know.

Comment: This is a general network configuration question and has nothing to do with Raspberry Pi. There is no much to do with the RasPi. You should better ask at https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a wpa_supplicant.conf

```
country=YOUR_COUNTRY_CODE
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="YOUR_WIFI_SSID"
    psk="YOUR_WIFI_PASSWORD"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

and replacing the ssid and psk with your shared iphone wifi?

This link would be helpful - https://www.taygan.co/blog/2018/03/08/setup-a-raspberry-pi-with-no-keyboard-or-monitor-headless

Good luck!